# Можно ли удалить из html-тега контент по медиа-запросу

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Допустим есть заголовок h1.
Для больших экранов содержимое этого тега представляет длинную строку.
При уменьшении экрана до мобильной версии, нужно *оставить* этот тег, но сократить содержимое - сделать короткий заголовок.
И наоборот, при увеличении экрана вернуть длинный заголовок.

Возможно ли из CSS в медиа-запросах манипулировать содержимым тегов, или это нужно делать средствами языка программирования JS/TS?

Comment: Строго говоря, css не может "удалить" html, но может его скрыть

Comment: @Александр удалять html НЕ нужно, нужно менять его содержимое.
Пример:
 было -  `<h1> Длинный, длинный, длинный заголовок</h1>`
 стало - `<h1> Короткий заголовок </h1>`

Comment: @TupoScrip хм, тогда конечно нужен JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно, вот так:

```css
#myHeader::before {
  content: 'Hello, World!'
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
  #myHeader::before {
    content: 'Hello, ...'
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeader"></h1>
```

Но вообще правильней будет сделать вот так:

```css
.adaptive-header .mobile-header {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .adaptive-header .desktop-header {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .adaptive-header .mobile-header {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="adaptive-header">
  <span class="desktop-header">Hello, World!</span>
  <span class="mobile-header">Hello, ...</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь там стиль была для автономно рендеринга этих трех точек. Сейчас ищу.

Comment: `..., там был стиль для автономного ...`*

Comment: Про псевдо-элементы я думал. А без псевдо-элементов не получится сделать?
Или может держать два заголовка в разметке и при изменении ширины экрана, переключать их через display: none?

Comment: @TupoScrip я как раз, так и сделал во втором решении.

Comment: Во класс, то что нужно. Моя мысль тоже как раз вокруг этого крутилась :)

Comment: @TupoScrip ага, я вот тоже минутку подумал и решил также сделать :). Если вы считаете что мой ответ решил вашу задачу (то есть ответил на вопрос), отметьте его галочкой пожалуйста :p (Она слева от ответа)

Comment: Да я хотел отметить, но нужно чтобы с момента вопроса прошло 5 минут, немного терпения :)

Answer (score 2):

#### С помощью CSS

```css
h1 {
  max-width: 200px;
}

h1.clip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="clip">Слишком длинный заголовок</h1>
```

Comment: Хм, где-то я это уже видел. Интересное решение, только осталось сделать всё по условиям вопроса. (Для мобильных устройств показывать только часть, для десктопа всё)

Comment: Интересное решения. Я правильно понял длинный заголовок просто обрезается, причём с конца строки? 
Если это так, то это немного не гибкое решение, т.к. нужно этот заголовок не просто обрезать, а переформулировать  и дать сокращённый вариант. Т.е. исходная (длинная) строка и конечная (короткая строка) могут состоять из разных слов.

Comment: @ΝNL993 в гугле пишите 'clip long text css', первая [ссылка на доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) выходит.

Comment: @TupoScrip да. Если вам нужно обрезать с конкретного места, пользуйтесь вариантом NNL993.

Comment: @eccs0103 с меня голос "за", не знал раньше, что CSS так может.

Comment: @eccs0103 Пока да, остановлюсь на решении от NNL993.  В любом случае спасибо вам за ответ, возможно подобное решение так же пригодится мне в будущем :)